# How did Birch and Swinnerton Dyer arrive at their conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, birch-swinnerton-dyer

I suspect that they knew that the $L-$function is defined only for $Re(s) \gt 3/2$.  Did they attempt to evaluate the $L-$function at $s=1$ by plugging $s=1$ in the infinite product  $\prod_p (\frac{1}{1-a_pp^{-s}+p^{1-2s}})$?  I think that it gives $\prod (\frac{N_p}{p})^{-1}$, which does not make sense under the usual definition of infinite product.

Note: I have posted the same at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/comment-on-heuristic-approach-of-b-s-d-conjecture) but I would like further explanation beyond what was given there.

Comment: See K. Conrad's very nice answer to this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25360/convergence-of-l-series


Comment: See also K. Conrad's paper  http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/eulerprod.pdf

Comment: Another related question is at mathoverflow.net/questions/60544/a-remark-of-mordell-alluding-to-a-local-global-principle-for-cubic-diophantine-eq/60549#60549.

Comment: @francois brunault:its the greatness of person who gives the information,like you,i am in debt with you,for your answer,and its very useful

Comment: A basic idea underlying the BSD conjecture is that if the elliptic curve has infinitely many rational points, then by reducing these points modulo various primes, it makes sense to expect that N_p is "high", so it is plausible that the above infinite product goes to 0. Note that this argument doesn't use the L-function at all.

Comment: @charles :thanks a lot for your help,it was quite useful

Comment: @francois:but it uses the L-function,as we get the value $\prod (N_{p}/p)^{-1}$,at $s=1$ ,when we plug that into the L-function,if so i think that if we plug according to your idea,if you put s=0,we get $\prod (1/N_{p})$ ,so which according to your argument must converge still faster compared to $\prod (N_{p}/p)^{-1}$,so can we state that the elliptic curve has infinitely many points if $L(E,0)=0$ 

Comment: I still don't think using MO to discuss very advanced number theory is a better approach to learning some basic algebra and number theory

Comment: ok yemon please keep your assumptions and conclusions with you,and i did not post a meaningless question or a basic question as you people close it off,this question is good i think so,but dont please close it i am looking for some help,let it be that i am an illiterate,but leave it , so if you are thinking to be very local,i challenge you to answer then,which shows your proficiency@yemon choi

Comment: iyengar, my (lack of) proficiency is not the issue. My concern is that since you are asking about very technical mathematics, it is not clear how much of the answers you actually understand. If you understand all of it, then great; but myself, I am trying to give advice that may help, believe it or not. You would be better off looking up material in Davenport's Higher Arithmetic, or Stewart and Tall's Algebraic Number Theory, and working through those and asking questions when you get stuck.

Comment: @trust god : I meant that the conjecture can be stated without mentioning the $L$-function (but then the equivalence with the modern form of the conjecture is not clear). Regarding the infinite product you mention, it goes to 0 since $1/N_p \to 0$ as $p \to \infty$. In fact it is a (deep) theorem that for any elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{Q}$, the function $L(E,s)$ has a simple zero at $s=0$, regardless of the rank of $E$.

Comment: In formulating their conjecture, Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer were strongly motivated by evidence in the case of CM elliptic curves, for which the analytic properties of the L-function have been understood since work of Hecke and Deuring in the 1920s/30s.  See e.g. Swinnerton-Dyer's article in Cassels-Frohlich.  Also, for two-variable quadratic forms, the product $\prod_{p} N_p/p$ essentially recovers a Dirichlet L-function at $s=1$.

Comment: @yemon :but the things you have said are not available here,and thats why i am depending on these things,really i crack my brain to understand these things,imagine yourself to have no education and reading mathematics yourself ,then you get my point 


Comment: @trust god. There are many books on algebraic number theory or arithmetic geometry available online.

Comment: @iyengar: you are missing my point. If you don't have access to more basic mathematical texts, the solution is not to ask specialists on the internet about some of the most intricate or deepest mathematics currently known, which moreover **depends** on understanding a whole bunch of other things which you also haven't learned. You seem to believe that one can somehow avoid doing this. If you do not have access to mathematical education, asking people about BSD, Hodge, etc is not going to be a substitute. You will, IMHO, benefit more from learning basic things than by asking about cool things 

Comment: @trust god. "imagine yourself to have no education and reading mathematics yourself" We've all had to go through this type of phase. But like Yemon already pointed out to you in a different Question, we all started at  the basics. I just don't understand why you insist not doing so yourself. There is no shame in doing this, EVERYONE else did so too.

Comment: Put it this way: why do you think your time is better spent "cracking your brain" trying to understand very hard problems in modern number theory, rather than learning the prerequisites? If you have no education and are reading mathematics yourself then it is even more important that you learn to do the basic things well. Try reading the online notes of J. S. Milne or Paul Garrett, for instance. There is plenty of interesting mathematics out there which is not as hard as the BSD conjecture...

Comment: By the way, Gerry Myerson appears to have given an answer to this question over at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36367/comment-on-heuristic-approach-of-b-s-d-conjecture/36369#36369 and it seems to me that "analytic continuation" is indeed the answer to your question. You seem to imply you didn't like that answer, though

Comment: The original version of this question made my eyes hurt.  I think I preserved the main idea.

Comment: Following Scott, I took the liberty of adding a link to the MathStackexchange version while clarifying that the OP is after more than what was given in GM's answer there. (For the record, I have not downvoted or upvoted this question, not have I voted to close.)

Comment:  What's wrong with reading the original articles by Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer? And I am repeating myself when I say that I miss some civility in trust god's comments. 

Comment: @yemon choi:sorry if i have said something harsh,but why do you bother about my understanding,let anyone post something,if i understand them well and good,if not i try to understand them,but i dont accept that ,when you say i must read algebraic geometry,i have already read those things,thats why i am posing such questions

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For what it's worth, here are some historical comments.

Both Birch and S-D spoke in Cambridge a few weeks ago, on the history of their conjecture. To my surprise, both of them emphasized the role not of the $L$-function, but of the Tamagawa number, in their comments on how it all came about.

Tamagawa had introduced this invariant associated to a semisimple algebraic group over a number field, and one can interpret it adelically or as a product of local factors. B and S--D were trying to "compute the Tamagawa number of an elliptic curve" -- or more precisely, to see what the analogue should be in this situation. The local factors came out to be $N_p/p$, at least at the good primes. Historically, the $L$-function came later. I asked S--D why this might have been, and he said something like "Weil was pushing the $L$-function as being of central importance, so, naturally, everyone else was avoiding it like the plague". I am not sure this comment is to be taken so seriously -- this is perhaps more a reflection of S-D's sense of humour (he'd made some rather caustic comments about Mordell's bridge playing skills earlier, again probably just to get laughs, and he succeeded admirably in getting them). But you have to remember the resources available to them at the time: they were initially not thinking about the $L$-function, but they did have this access to this gigantic machine, the size of a lecture theatre, that was capable of computing the product of $N_p/p$ for all primes less than 1000, and this for them was basically a miracle, because ten years prior to that if you wanted to do this calculation then you'd better have a lot of pencils/paper handy.

So they used what they had, they were focussed initially on Tamagawa numbers (this is I guess the reason that the fudge factors at the bad primes became known as Tamagawa factors?), they had access to a computing machine and S--D knew how to use it, and perhaps crucially one should stress that whilst we *now* know the $L$-function to be of central importance, it was perhaps not so clear at that time. There was no Langlands programme, there was no converse theorem -- this was the late 50s. It was only a couple of years later, when Birch was talking to Shimura, that Shimura told him that in the CM case one could actually evaluate the $L$-function at 1 in concrete cases and get concrete numbers, and then Davenport told Birch a concrete algorithm which would work and could be done by hand. I have seen with my own eyes the piece of paper in which Davenport sketched the idea to Birch, and Birch has written "keep this" on the top and underlined it! Birch then proceeds to compute various explicit examples of special values of $L$-functions on the next few pages, in the CM case, but maybe this was already after the first work had been published.

I mentioned all this to Rene Schoof yesterday and he claimed that there were pictures of the pieces of paper on youtube of all places (I know William Stein was taking pictures frantically -- my eyes were just popping out of my head -- all these really important historical documents, that Birch claimed were just gathering dust in a wardrobe at home!).

Comment: I am not surprised about the Tamagawa number emphasis. I think I heard the same, maybe from Birch awhile ago. This was big stuff back in the late 50s, when done for quadratic forms.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer said at this conference (which unfortunately I didn't attend). The Tamagawa numbers also seem to have had a significant role in the development of the conjectures of special values of L-functions at other integers. For example, Bloch-Kato's article in the Grothendieck Festschrift is named "L-functions and Tamagawa numbers of motives", and the conjecture predicting the exact leading term of a L-function at an integer is still called the Tamagawa number conjecture.

Comment: @Buzzard: here are some videos

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcMgwfsP0u0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIN2__t5Bsk&feature=related
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo9yWAhBxAs&feature=related
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bX4Vdn7CwI&feature=related

there seem to be no official videos from the talks at the BSD conference 2011, but...

Comment: Kevin, $a_p/p$ or $N_p/p$?

Comment: I am surprised no one has mentioned that Dirichlet's class number formula must have been had some relevance in suggesting a conjecture to B+S-D especially in the form $L^{(r)}(0,\chi)$ where $r$ is the unit rank. It is though not the same as the critical strip is shifted.

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE REPOST YOUR ANSWER MORE CLEARLY SIR,I FOUND YOUR ANSWER INTERESTING BUT ITS VERY SHORT,ANY ELABORATED VERSION IS APPRECIATED AND THANKS A LOT FOR THAT SIR@JUNKIE


Comment: @Junkie: I was surprised too. I think this observation, whilst clearly analogous in retrospect, might have been a while coming, because B and SD were not initially focussed on the $L$-function but clearly knew they were on to something. I keep meaning to look at the first paper they wrote on the subject, to see whether it mentions $L$-functions at all.

Comment: @trust god: your comments indicate precisely why you should follow Yemon's advice and learn some basic undergraduate number theory before you start trying to understand profound conjectures which are generalising things you don't know.

Comment: who told i dont know those things,i know them infact,do you have any gauge to test me by seeing this question ,i told i have done it already,and its not an amateur question ok,@kevin Buzzard

Comment: My gauge is the fact that you seem to be claiming that you don't understand Junkie's comment. My humble suggestion to you is that you don't ask Junkie to elaborate, but that instead you pick up a book which is at an appropriate level for you.

Comment: but the elaboration was not due to my lack of understanding,but i want still more to hear about it,like any references@kevin

Comment: @trust god: Junkie's comment is perfectly clear as is. Just because you vaguely know what some big words mean, doesn't mean you understand things.  I used to spend large amounts of time "thinking" about hard problems whose subtleties I didn't understand at all; I now regard this as wasted time.  Don't waste your time like that too.

Comment: Another historic question for $L^{(r)}$ is, whether the theory of heights was widespread then, for to form the regulator. Neron/Tate had only recently (maybe published only later?) shown the canonical definition, though prospectively one could surmise there was "some" right definition on $E(Q)=Z^r$ that gave a "regulator" object.

Comment: IIRC one of Birch or S-D explicitly mentioned that they didn't know about the canonical height at the time. Again this is worth checking in the literature but my impression was that the order was (a) growth of $\prod_p N_p/p$ controlled by rank, (b) introduction of the $L$-function and notion that order of vanishing of $L$-function was the rank, (c) formal statement of conjecture as we know it, only made possible after canonical height was introduced. Again this is probably easy to check with a literature search...I really should look at those early BSD papers! I'm ashamed that I haven't...

Comment: @Junkie, Kevin: my reading is that the complete statement of the BSD including the regulator part, as we know it today, is due to Tate. In "Notes on elliptic curves II" in Crelle, B and S-D briefly say that "there was some tendency for $\prod N_p/p$ to be large when the generators of $A$ were small", but they don't pursue this further. Tate in "On the BSD and a geometric analogue" gives the formula we know today, including the regulator. In "Conjectures concerning elliptic curves", Proc. Symp. Pure Math. Vol VIII, Birch explicitly credits Tate with this formulation (penultimate paragraph).

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60544/a-remark-of-mordell-alluding-to-a-local-global-principle-for-cubic-diophantine-eq/60549#60549